# RecyclerView not loading

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, lifecycle

I have created a Recycler view that is supposed to be created when the activity is created. Currently, when I click a button on my MainActivity, an intent launches the ListActivity which has my recyclerview but it doesn't load. I have used toast message to confirm that each method is getting called, and that I am getting the correct data from the API. If I reset the activity using the restart activity option in Android Studio the Recycler shows up and functions correctly. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my ListActivity:

````
    private RecyclerView myrecyclerview;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter myadapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mylayoutmanager;
    static RequestQueue listqueue;
    static final private String url = "https://swapi.dev/api/people/";

    static ArrayList<RecyclerItem> list = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        listqueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        myrecyclerview = findViewById(R.id.characterlist);
        

        myadapter = new MyAdapter(list, this);
        myrecyclerview.setAdapter(myadapter);
        myrecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mylayoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        myrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(mylayoutmanager);
        parseJsonData();
    }

    public void parseJsonData(){
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonarray = response.getJSONArray("results");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String name = jsonobject.getString("name");
                            String height = jsonobject.getString("height");
                            String mass = jsonobject.getString("mass");
                            String eyecolor = jsonobject.getString("eye_color");
                            String birthyear = jsonobject.getString("birth_year");

                            //list.add(new RecyclerItem("darth vader", "200", "128", "1950", "red"));
                            list.add(new RecyclerItem(name, "Height: " + height, "Mass: " + mass, "Birth Year: " + birthyear, eyecolor));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

        listqueue.add(request);

    }


    @Override
    public void onCharacterClick(int position) {
        String color = list.get(position).getEyecolor();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), color, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

} ```

Like I mentioned, once I reload the activity, it works correctly. But I want the recycler view to show when I navigate to the activity.
````

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the first time that the activity is create, `list` is empty and `parseJsonData()` is running on the background filling that list.
Once you reload the activiy, the list and adapter are filled therefore when you call

```
myadapter = new MyAdapter(list, this);
myrecyclerview.setAdapter(myadapter);
myrecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
mylayoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
myrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(mylayoutmanager);
```

the recycler view is show. Try to do this on your `parseJsonData()`; after the loop ends, then create the adapter and show the rv

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
   ....
}

myadapter = new MyAdapter(list, this);
....
myrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(mylayoutmanager);
```

Comment: You are a rock star! Thank you so much for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

**I hope it help for u**

*Creat a List*

```
private List< TipsList > tipsLists = new ArrayList<>();
```

*SET UP RECYCLERVIEW LIKE THIS*

```
RecyclerView tipsRv = findViewById(R.id.tips_rv);
    TipsAdapter adapter = new TipsAdapter(tipsLists, this);
    tipsRv.setAdapter(adapter);
    tipsRv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    tipsRv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

*getDATA*

```
 public void getWallis() {
    String myJSONStr = method.loadJSON();

    try {
        JSONObject ROOT_OBJ = new JSONObject(myJSONStr);
        JSONArray MAIN_ARRAY = ROOT_OBJ.getJSONArray("ff_api");
        JSONObject TIPS_OBJ = MAIN_ARRAY.getJSONObject(3);
        JSONArray TIPS_ARRAY = TIPS_OBJ.getJSONArray("Tips");

        for (int i = 0; i < TIPS_ARRAY.length(); i++) {
            TipsList tipsList = new TipsList();
            JSONObject jsonObject = TIPS_ARRAY.getJSONObject(i);
            tipsList.setId(jsonObject.getInt("id"));
            tipsList.setTipsTitle(jsonObject.getString("tipsTitle"));
            tipsList.setTipsDec(jsonObject.getString("tipsDec"));
            tipsLists.add(tipsList);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Create an Adapter Class